# How do I use elements from html in javascript for an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I have a html web page that picks a video game for you based on the platform and genre.

When user selects platform and genre from a dropdown and then clicks the `Find game` button. How do I take those choices from platform and genre and output a game after they click `Find Game`?

**Example:** When user selects xbox and shooter. He presses "Find game". Then the web page shows "Gears of War".

**HTML:**

```
    <label for="platformType">
        Platform
    </label>
    <select name="platform" id="platformType">
        <option value="PC">(Choose Platform)</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        <option value="PS4">Playstation 4</option>
        <option value="switch">Switch</option>
        <option value="xbox">Xbox One</option>  
    </select>


    <label for="genreType">
        Genre
    </label>
    <select name="genre" id="genreType">
        <option value="PC">(Choose Genre)</option>
        <option value="Action">Action/Adventure</option>
        <option value="Fighter">Fighter</option>
        <option value="MMO">MMO</option>
        <option value="MOBA">MOBA</option>
        <option value="OpenWorld">Open World</option>
        <option value="Platformer">Platformer</option>
        <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
        <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
        <option value="Shooter">Shooter</option>
        <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Find Game" id="Submit" />
```

Comment: What JavaScript have you written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can add more games in the games object.

```js
var games=[{name:'Forza',platform:'xbox',genre:'Racing'}]
var genre;
var platform;
$("#platformType").change(function(){
platform=$(this).val()
})
$("#genreType").change(function(){
genre=$(this).val()
})
$("#Submit").click(function(){games.filter((e)=>e.platform==platform && e.genre==genre?console.log(e.name):false)})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="platformType">
        Platform
    </label>
    <select name="platform" id="platformType">
        <option value="PC">(Choose Platform)</option>
        <option value="PC">PC</option>
        <option value="PS4">Playstation 4</option>
        <option value="switch">Switch</option>
        <option value="xbox">Xbox One</option>  
    </select>


    <label for="genreType">
        Genre
    </label>
    <select name="genre" id="genreType">
        <option value="PC">(Choose Genre)</option>
        <option value="Action">Action/Adventure</option>
        <option value="Fighter">Fighter</option>
        <option value="MMO">MMO</option>
        <option value="MOBA">MOBA</option>
        <option value="OpenWorld">Open World</option>
        <option value="Platformer">Platformer</option>
        <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
        <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
        <option value="Shooter">Shooter</option>
        <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Find Game" id="Submit" />
```